# Multiple background images, not all centered

Tags: css, background-image, z-index

I'm trying to add multiple background-images to a DOM element (a td) using CSS. I can specify multiple background images that stack on top of each other like so:

```
td{
    background-image: url("img1.svg"), url("img2.svg");
}
```

This results in img2 being stacked on top of img1. However, I need to specify that one background image should be off-center, while the other centered. Is there a way to do this in CSS, or will I need to get fancy to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just do the same with the position rule:

```
td{
    background-image: url("img1.svg"), url("img2.svg");
    background-position: center center, left top;  /* or */
    background-position: center center, 0px 0px;   /* x y */
}
```

The first apply to the first image, the second to the second image and so forth.

For more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: It should be `left top`. Although when you use keywords it doesn't matter but when you using pixels, it'll interpreted as `Xpx Ypx` and not `Ypx Xpx`

Comment: @Sourabh you are absolutely right. Corrected to left top. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-position` property

```
background-position: left top, center center;
```

You can use `background` shorthand property if you wan't to type less. I really prefer shorthands.

[**+`background-position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbackground-position) [**+`background`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)